# Hyperledger Fabric on Kubernetes - Restarting Peer throw error for few minutes

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric2.2

I have setup for 3 organisations on `Kubernetes` cluster and it is giving me following error when I restart peer node pod and tried command -> `peer channel list` on bash shell,

```
[comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> ERRO 026 Client TLS handshake failed after 2.997205009s with error: context canceled remoteaddress=10.0.94.178:7051

[grpc] WarningDepth -> DEBU 027 [core]grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {peer0-org1:7051 peer0-org1:7051 <nil> 0 <nil>}. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: context canceled". Reconnecting...
Error: error getting endorser client for channel: endorser client failed to connect to peer0-org1:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

After some time (nearly 10-15 minutes) if I tried same command,

```
[comm.tls] ClientHandshake -> DEBU 024 Client TLS handshake completed in 1.48399ms remoteaddress=10.0.94.178:7051
[grpc] InfoDepth -> DEBU 025 [core]Subchannel Connectivity change to READY
```

It seems working and give me channel list. I am not able to find out what is reason behind this, Please help for this.